# Symlink for Currently Selected Alert Sound?

Tags: 18.04, sound

Is there a symlink or other way to get the path to the currently selected alert sound (as selected through the main settings)? I'm looking to have my Tunderbird new mail sound match my alert sound, and don't want to have to worry about selecting the new sound when I change it in the main settings.

Answer (score 4):

***Workaround***

Seems there are no schemas for setting the alert sound options those are available via GUI

[image]

Observations:

Sound theme can be set with `gsettings`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name 'mySoundTheme'
```

to see the current theme.. run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name`

Example:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name
'ubuntu'
$
```

when Bark is selected from the GUI, It uses same `ubuntu` theme but instead of the file `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.oga` it uses `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/bark.ogg`

when Drip is selected it uses drip.ogg, in the same way for Glass and Sonar also.

In all the above 4 Selections, the system sound theme is constant which is `ubuntu` which is used by the Thunderbird.

[image]

When the option "Default system sound for new mail" is selected in Thunderbird it uses `message.ogg` file for new mails and `bell.ogg` file for alerts from the custom theme

Note that the names in some custom downloaded themes may vary for message.ogg and bell.ogg etc..

So the idea is to create 4 Custom Sound Themes with name bark, drip, glass & sonar..

to do so, just copy `ubuntu` directory and rename it with above names..

replace the files `message.ogg` and `bell.ogg` with the sounds you wish in all the four directories bark, drip, glass & sonar..

now you can choose the custom theme you want with `gsettings` command or via `dconf-editor` tool which can be installed with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name 'bark'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name 'drip'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name 'glass'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name 'sonar'
```

If you want to reset, run below command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.sound theme-name
```

to remove the options from GUI for any accidental selection of "Choose an alert sound"

rename the file `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/sounds/gnome-sounds-default.xml` to anything you wish..

[image]

[image]

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.2, Worked as intended.