# Disabling system sounds and alerts without disabling application notification sounds

Tags: sound, thunderbird, notification

Is there a way to disable all alerts without disabling notifications for certain apps? For instance, every time I adjust the volume with the keyboard it plays an annoying bing sound, and the only way I know to disable it is to mute System Sounds in settings. This is fine except muting System Sounds mutes the notification sound that plays whenever my thunderbird inbox receives a new message.
[image: System Sounds]

Comment: by removing other sounds and adding notifications sounds only in particular sound theme folder.. you can acheive what you are l00king f0r..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1149567/739431 may help

Comment: I managed to disable all alert sounds with the dconf editor, and I can prevent the volume adjustment sound by pressing alt+volume up/down.