# Change terminal beep from drip to glass using command line?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 21.10

How can I change the terminal beep from the default "drip" to "glass"?

I know I can open Settings, select Sound, and then, in the Alert Sound section, select "Glass".

How can this change be achieved using the command line?

Comment: Theoretically it should be inside GSettings database, check with `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.sound` .

Comment: @PJSingh this post may give some idea? https://askubuntu.com/a/1149567/739431

Comment: @UnKNOWn, thanks-- your tip lead me to the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Example alert sounds are stored in `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts`:

   ```
   ls -1 /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/
   bark.ogg
   drip.ogg
   glass.ogg
   sonar.ogg
   ```
2. The sound themes are stored in `/usr/share/sounds`:

   ```
   ls -1 /usr/share/sounds
   alsa
   freedesktop
   gnome
   sf2
   sf3
   sound-icons
   speech-dispatcher
   Yaru
   ```
3. The default sound theme is `freedesktop`.
4. Based on this information, we can replace the `bell.ogg` file in the `freedesktop` directory with the `glass.ogg` file from `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/`.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/
   sudo mv bell.oga bell.oga.original
   sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg ./bell.ogg
   ```
5. To make the change effective, log-out and log-back-in, or toggle your sound theme using a tool like [Gnome Tweaks](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/gnome-tweaks) or [Dconf editor](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/dconf-editor).

---

Thanks to [@UnKNOWn](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/unknown) for pointing me in the right direction. The link to the other answer, [Symlink for Currently Selected Alert Sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149498/symlink-for-currently-selected-alert-sound/1149567#1149567), that UnKNOWn provided may be the more "proper" way of changing the system's alert sound, but I didn't want to create a whole new sound theme just to change this one sound.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder `/usr/share/sounds/Yaru` into a new folder `/usr/share/sounds/myBell`

```
sudo cp -a /usr/share/sounds/Yaru /usr/share/sounds/myBell
```

Then open `index.theme`

```
sudo nano /usr/share/sounds/myBell/index.theme
```

and change its content like below:

```
[Sound Theme]
Name=myBell
Directories=myBell

[stereo]
OutputProfile=stereo
```

Go to Settings and change sound like below:

[image]